# Implementing F# Backtracking

Tags: f#, implementation, backtracking

I've been playing with a well-known knapsack problem. This time - however - I decided to implement it in F#, as I'm learning the language and find it particularly interesting.

I've managed to implement the main part of the algorithm, but I need backtracking as well. Unfortunately, all the information I found on the web used Haskell, which I don't know (yet ;) ).

As a placeholder I implemented backtracking using mutable variables
(without going into much details, "combinations (i, k)" return a partial solution for i items and capacity of k ):

```
let output = 
    List.rev
        [
            let i = ref N
            let k = ref K
            // analize items starting with the last one
            for item in Array.rev items do
                match !k - item.Size with
                // if size of i-th item is greater than current capacity...
                | x when x <  0 -> i := !i - 1
                       // ... this means we haven't taken this item
                                   yield 0
                // otherwise we've got two cases
                | x when x >= 0 -> let v1 = combinations (!i-1, !k) id
                                   let vc = combinations (!i, !k) id
                                   if v1 = vc then 
                                    // case 1: item hasn't been taken
                                    i := !i - 1
                                    yield 0
                                   else
                                     // case 2: item is contained in the optimal solution
                                    i := !i - 1
                                    k := x
                                    yield 1
        ]

List.iter (fun x -> printf "%A " x) output
```

I believe there is a better way to do this in F# (e.g. using computation expressions). I'd be very glad to hear any tips/information about how to implement this in functional style.

Last thing: please remember I'm new to functional programming and try to avoid some magic expressions like the one I found:

"a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general pattern that you can use in this case is *folding*. This is useful when you need to walk over a list (like `items`, in your case) and keep some state as you go (`i` and `k`, in your case). This can be implemented using the higher-order function `Array.fold` (as you are working with arrays):

```
let results, _, _ = items |> Array.rev |> Array.fold (fun (resultsSoFar, i, k) item ->
  match k - item.Size with
  // if size of i-th item is greater than current capacity...
  | x when x <  0 -> 
      // ... this means we haven't taken this item
      (0::resultsSoFar, i - 1, k)
  // otherwise we've got two cases
  | x when x >= 0 -> 
      let v1 = combinations (i-1, !k) id
      let vc = combinations (i, !k) id
      if v1 = vc then 
        // case 1: item hasn't been taken
        (0::resultsSoFar, i - 1, k)
      else
        (1::resultsSoFar, i - 1, x) ) ([], N, K)
```

The idea is that the function gets previous state `(resultsSoFar, i, k)` and the current `item` and should return new state - for example, if we want to produce `0` and decrement `i`, we can return `(0::resultsSoFar, i - 1, k)` as you can see in the first case.

The initial state is the last argument `([], N, K)` and you get the result consisting of all three values, so I'm using pattern `results, _, _` to ignore the last value of `i` and `k`.

Note that your code was not complete, so I could not run the snippet (there may be bugs!) but I hope it demonstrates the general idea. You could also implement the same thing using a recursive function, or recursive sequence expression (in both cases, you would keep the state in arguments and you would use pattern matching on lists to handle the case when it is empty or when it is non-empty).

The approach using recursive sequence expression is perhaps closer to your imperative version:

```
let rec lookup (i, k) items = seq {
  match items with
  | [] -> ()
  | item::items ->
      match k - item.Size with
      // if size of i-th item is greater than current capacity...
      | x when x <  0 -> 
          // ... this means we haven't taken this item
          yield 0
          yield! lookup (i - 1, k) items
      // otherwise we've got two cases
      | x when x >= 0 -> 
          let v1 = combinations (i-1, !k) id
          let vc = combinations (i, !k) id
          if v1 = vc then 
            // case 1: item hasn't been taken
            yield 0
            yield! lookup (i - 1, k) items
          else
            yield 1
            yield! lookup (i - 1, x) items }
```